# Quasar q-select @new-value not triggering on mobile

Tags: cordova, quasar-framework

I am developing a cordova mobile application using Quasar components and I am stuck with the q-select not triggering `@new-value` event on the mobile app. [Documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#Using-menu-and-filtering) states that it listens for key enter event but on mobile I am not sure how it will trigger. I have a form with q-select and other inputs. What I want is that when someone enters new value in q-select and go to next input the `@new-value` should trigger but this is not happening. Maybe someone from the community can help me.

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-select
      filled
      v-model="model"
      use-input
      use-chips
      multiple
      input-debounce="0"
      @new-value="createValue"
      :options="filterOptions"
      @filter="filterFn"
      style="width: 250px"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any additional detail like platform. I don't experience this on iOS. You may be experiencing [this known issue on GitHub](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/8494).

If this open issue seems to describe what you're experiencing, you can try something like the following. Note that I've added a `ref` so your component can access the child component's `inputValue`, removed the `@new-value` event, and added the `new-value-mode` prop, with the handler to add the value to the options list.

```
<template>
    <q-select
      ref="qSelect"
      filled
      v-model="model"
      use-input
      use-chips
      multiple
      input-debounce="0"
      new-value-mode="add"
      :options="filterOptions"
      @filter="filterFn"
      @keyup.enter="doAddInputValue"
      style="width: 250px"
    />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    doAddInputValue(inputValue) {
      if (this.$q.platform.is.ios) return

      const inputValue = this.$refs.qSelect.inputValue
      this.$refs.qSelect.add(inputValue, 'add-unique')
    }
  }
}
```

**Some additional notes:**

If you desire different functionality, e.g. add-unique or toggle, you will have to write your own handler, but the gist of this solution is to — until Quasar fix the issue you are experiencing — show you a workaround that you can implement with your own code.